# Trying to removed broken Acrobat Reader Plugin from IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, activex

I installed the latest version of Acrobat X today not realizing I was really installing XI. IE began to crash upon every exit. I traced the problem to Acrobat Reader XI. I uninstalled XI but one of the add-ins sticks around. I can't unregister it. IE9 maddeningly disables the Remove button for the control in Internet Options.

Anything else I can do aside from a System Restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it. In case someone is curious...

Using the Internet Options control panel and inspecting the Add-Ons, I found out the individual DLLs corresponding to the Reader XI software as well as their CLSID as they were referenced in the registry. I felt I could try to remove registry references and then try to install Reader X.

I removed the references in the registry, but did not remove the DLLs. I figured the Acrobat X installer would overwrite them.

I installed X, but found myself in the same looping crash. Looking at Add-Ins again, it was clear that the DLLs referenced for Reader were 11.x versions.

In the end, I found that the Reader X installer was not able to overwrite the XI DLLs. I manually removed them after taking ownership of the files. I then ran repair install of Reader X.

Problem resolved!